# Is there any lightweight framework for java IO/NIO client other than Netty or Apachae MINA

Tags: java, io, client, client-side, nio

I wish to create a client on java NIO/ IO.Is there any lightweight framework especially for client application. I created a server using Netty framework but its too heavy for client.so am looking for a lightweight frame work.

please help me to find out the best.

Any help is appreciable

Thank you

Comment: What sort of client application? Netty isn't particularly heavyweight... I'd be surprised if that is what is giving you problems.

Answer (score 2):

if you want light weight, I would use blocking IO or NIO. You could write a simple one with a class and an interface to suit your needs/protocol.